# Move Subfolders Up One Level

Tags: windows, command-line

I have this directory structure:

c:\Parent\Child1\Images\folder1
c:\Parent\Child1\Images\folder2
c:\Parent\Child1\Images\folder3
c:\Parent\Child2\Images\folder1
c:\Parent\Child2\Images\folder2
c:\Parent\Child3\Images\folder1
c:\Parent\Child3\Images\folder2
c:\Parent\Child3\Images\folder3
c:\Parent\Child3\Images\folder4
etc.

Using the command line (Windows7), I would like to move each folder1, folder2, folder3 etc... up one level to its respective "childX" folder.

I will then remove the "Images" folders (I know how to do that).

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell! If you `cd` into the `Parent` folder and run this command, it will rearrange your folders as you desire.

```
dir -Directory | % {Push-Location $_.FullName; dir './Images' | % {Move-Item $_.FullName .}; del './Images'; Pop-Location}
```

Translation:

- List all subfolders of the current directory
- For each one:

  - Make it the current directory
  - List all items in the folder named `Images`
  - For each one:

    - Move it to the current folder (your numbered child folders)
  - Delete the now-empty `Images` folder
  - Restore the current directory to what it was before (your `Parent`)

If you would prefer that the command not delete the `Images` folders, you can remove the `del './Images';` bit.